# UniqueValidator on serializer vs unique model constraint

Tags: django-rest-framework

I currently have a user model with a unique constraint on the username field. My understanding is that I can either add a UniqueValidator on the username field in the serializer, or else just let the database throw an IntegrityError when I go to save the model and then handle that.

It seems like adding the UniqueValidator on the serializer just creates extra queries and would have worse performance, but is there a good reason to do all the validation on the serializer rather than just letting the database throw an error?

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely. In DRF serializer is responsible for 2 things:

1. [de]serialize data so `dict <-> model`
2. validate data

The validation is super important. That effectively makes the serializer a gateway to your database. It checks the data and if data is no good, it compiles errors which can be returned to the user. If the data is valid, serializer can then further be used to interact with db such as creating/updating models. This however has implications. Now lets say that your serializer has nested serializers:

```
class FooSerializer(Serializer):
    ...

class BarSerializer(Serializer):
    foo = FooSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        foo = self.fields['foo'].create(validated_data['foo'])
        # create bar here
```

If `BarSerializer` does not enforce uniqueness of some field, in its `create`, `foo` can be created before `bar` will be created which can fail in database due to uniqueness violation. That is undesired since REST requests should be atomic (request should either succeed or fail but never partially succeed). There are ways to handle that by using db transactions however that can bring unnecessary complexity. If however uniqueness is enforced in serializer, there is much smaller chance that creation of bar will fail. Note that it can still fail in concurrent applications (two requests trying to do same thing at the same time and first request creates bar between second request's foo serializer validates data and saves bar). Checking uniqueness simply reduces the risk of a failure and allows requests to be more atomic with less db maintenance overhead.